# Error in beamer with only<2-> in lists

Tags: beamer, itemize

I don't understand what is and how to solve this problem. It says `LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. [   \end{frame}]`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \only<2->{\item test1}
            \only<3->{\item test2}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I change the `2` to `1` like this,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \only<1->{\item test1}
            \only<3->{\item test2}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the code works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that on the first overlay you would have an `enumerate` environment with no item, which is not allowed. You could workaround this by wrapping the whole `enumerate` in an environment which is only shown form the second overlay onwards, or (in my opinion much easier) use the build in overlay functionality of `\item`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item<2-> test1
            \item<3-> test2
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```